# What is the Gerrit Follow-up button doing?

Tags: gerrit

What is the "Follow-up" button in the Gerrit Review is doing? And when should it be used?

I am using Gerrit 2.13.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw this feature mentioned [here](http://blogs.collab.net/git/scm/gerrit-productivity-hacks-inline-edit#.WYy8oE5icUQ) and also played around with it a bit as I was curious myself.

> ...allows us to create a Follow-Up change. The Follow-Up changes are
>   changes that are based on existing changes. This gives you an
>   opportunity to create a chain of related changes.

The "follow-up" feature allows you to create change-sets very quickly.
The parent commit of these change-sets will be the change-set that they were created from (the change-set where the "follow-up" button was used).

This feature could be useful for when you are wrapping up a change but a few additional bugs or tweaks were found that you don't want to include in the current change-set.

You can create change-sets for those follow-up items rather than having to create the change-sets manually.

The text that is typed into the popup box after you click the follow-up button becomes the commit message for the new change-set.

Comment: So this is only like i would fetch that change-set and do a new one based on it and push it to gerrit. But this button creates this in browser only.