# How and When to use Follow Up feature of Gerrit efficiently?

Tags: gerrit

Can anyone help to elaborate with example, I tried to do it but didn't understand the end-to-end workflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621912/what-is-the-gerrit-follow-up-button-doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Gerrit Follow-up button doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621912/what-is-the-gerrit-follow-up-button-doing)

Comment: Existing question is a portion of this question. 
My question is about the end-to-end flow when we click on follow-up button, what to do next and why? 
Actually I clicked on this button on Gerrit & this created a new commit-ID with my new commit message, and enabled a option of 'publish'. Eventually i got two commits in Gerrit, one is original that is not merged and another is follow-up commit with new commit id. So, i was looking for end-to-end lifecycle of this feature to understand the use of this feature in real.